# How many equivalence relations are there on a set $E$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I was wondering, just out of pure curiosity, if anyone has ever studied the following function defined over a general space: Given $Ω$ an arbitrary universal set and $Ω^{'} \subseteq Ω$ which is finite,  define the function $R:Ω^{'} \to \mathbb N$ where $R(E)$ counts all the possible equivalence relations on $E \times E$. Now this function is well-defined, because we have that $R$ takes finite subsets as inputs, and so $R(E) \leq 2^{|E|^2}$ for all $E \subseteq Ω^{'}$.

Comment: Equivalence relations are equivalent to set partitions, so this is asking for the number of set partitions of a set $E$, a well-known problem. See https://oeis.org/A000110

Comment: @JairTaylor Is there a known formula, or at least a decent approximation?

Comment: There are approximations - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate